# How to change appearance of inline comment in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, faces

I use inline comments in org mode using:
`@@comment: this is a comment@@` (see method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27095959/12134180)).

I'd like to make `@@comment:` and `@@` disappear and the text within appear greyed out.

I set `(setq org-hide-emphasis-markers t)` and added `("@@" (:foreground "gray25" :background "black"))` to `org-emphasis-alist`. That did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Looking up in the org source where `org-emphasis-alist` is used, we find it is used in `org-do-emphasis-faces`. This function is added to [font-lock-keywords](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#index-font_002dlock_002dkeywords), after which font-lock fontifies the region corresponding to the `match-data`.
To hide the markers, `org-do-emphasis-faces` additionally adds 'invisible' text properties to those markers. In summary, the behavior you are asking for can be achieved by evaluating the following code before opening an org file (e.g. add it to your init file):

```lisp
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
                        '(("@@comment: .*@@" . 'shadow)
                          (org-do-font-lock-inline-comment)))


(defun org-do-font-lock-inline-comment (limit)
  (re-search-forward "\\(@@comment: \\).*\\(@@\\)" limit t)
  (add-text-properties (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)
                               '(invisible t))
  (add-text-properties (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2)
                               '(invisible t)))
```

where I have used the `shadow` face to 'grey out' the text.